# Standalone JBOSS7 uses more JVMSs?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jvm, jboss7.x

I would like to store some data in a static variables and I want all the webservices deployed on the same JBOSS7 to reach those data. I thought a standalone JBOSS runs in a single JVM and all the services run in the same JVM so they can access a static variable.

However I noticed that I got a NullPointerException when my webservice try to get the data.

This is my storage class:

```
public enum OneJvmCacheImpl {

    INSTANCE;

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> values = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

    public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(values.get(key));
    }

    ...     

}


OneJvmCacheImpl.INSTANCE.get(...);
```

Can you please advise me why I cannot access the **values** from my webservice?
Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by deployments mean separate war files, the static variables will not be visible to the other webservices in other war files as they are loaded by different classloaders. Each war has it's own classloader, and hence it's own "class instance" of the class. You could perhaps solve it by moving the class in question to a place where it's shared amongst the deployments, but I would suggest that you solve it otherwise anyway, either by using the database or a distributed cache.

Comment: Hi NilsH, sorry for the late answer and thank you for enlighten me! What do you think, could I use the Guava cache for this? Thanks again, Viktor

Answer (score 1):

jBoss definitely won't allow you to share static variables across different deployments. That would be a huge security issue, what if I deploy a war next to yours and start changing your static variables...

You need to persist such values in something else like a database, memcache or shared file.

Comment: Hi Andreas, sorry for the late answer. Thank you for answering my question. Would Guava cache be appropriate for me? thanks, V.

Comment: I don't know if guava caches can use a backend that can be shared. I've only used it in process and that way wouldn't work for you.